# Adding Foreign Key Constraint

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a table, but I had a problem with `foreign key`
this is the script I tried :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS note_etudiant(
    num_insc int auto_increment,
    cin int foreign key references T_utilisateur(cin),
    nom varchar(25),
    note float
)Engine=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

And this is the error I got :

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'foreign key references T_utilisateur(cin),
>           nom varchar(25),
>           no' at line 3

Answer (score 0):

You need to list your foreign key constraint after your column creation

```
cin int,
constraint foreign key (cin) references T_utilisateur(cin),
```

Comment: when I tried this I got this error : `1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`, so I defined the column `num_insc` as primary key and then I got this error : `1005 - Can't create table 'gestion_note.note_etudiant' (errno: 150) `

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the foreign key separately from the column. I also recommend creating the index separately so you can control the name of the index.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS note_etudiant(
    num_insc int auto_increment,
    cin int,
    nom varchar(25),
    note float,
    primary key (num_insc),
    key cin (cin),
    constraint fk_note_etudiant_to_t_utilisateur foreign key (cin) references T_utilisateur(cin)
)Engine=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: I tried this script and I got this error : `1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key `

Comment: this won't work either, this is the error I got :

`1005 - Can't create table 'gestion_note.note_etudiant' (errno: 150)`

Comment: Is `T_utilisateur.cin` a primary key, or at least a unique key? Is it a signed int? Run this command and look for "LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR" to get more details on the error: `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G`